# Firebase functions grouping without name change

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I was recommended by the Firebase support representative to use function grouping to deploy the functions better. However, I noticed on function grouping the name of functions changes For eg. the function name `Ferrari` changes to `cars-Ferrari`. For database, periodic, and auth triggers I don't mind the name change but for HTTP functions that are already being used in production, I can't change the name because of two reasons, one because it is already deployed and I can't update one of the builds because of stability and second I don't want group name to be visible for few HTTP functions because I don't want reverse engineering to be done easily. So, I will have two copies of the same function because I am observing in the Dashboard there are two entries for the same function with the grouped and ungrouped names, I don't want that too. If I don't use grouping for `https` functions then the deploys become inefficient and I can't deploy similar functions using one command and If I use grouping I get two functions with the same logic.

So is there a way to group `http` functions without changing the name of the function, I still want the `Ferarri` function to be deployed as `Ferarri`, no group name ahead of it?

Also, I wanted to know whether the presence of both groupedName(`cars-Ferrari`) and ungroupedName(`Ferrari`) function database functions at the same path with the same trigger eg. `onWrite` make the function run twice If both the grouped and ungrouped name are being shown in the firebase console dashboard or is only the latest deployed function runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you group the functions they will have the perfix as the group name and a `-` after it. You can't group them without having that.

Because of such cases I always recommend to use the Firebase hosting to rewrite specific routes to specific functions in case you need to change the name like here.

This is an example how we do it in one of your projects:

```js
"hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/v1/visimatch",
        "function": "https-apiV1VisimatchOnRequest"
      },
      {
        "source": "/api/v1/container_tasks",
        "function": "https-apiV1ContainerTasksOnRequest"
      },
      {
        "source": "/api/v1/container_tasks/:uid*",
        "function": "https-apiV1ContainerTasksOnRequest"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
```

As you can notice we use grouped functions here to.

[Here](https://codeburst.io/organizing-your-firebase-cloud-functions-67dc17b3b0da) you can find more how we organize our cloud functions.